# Is type unification a kind of search for alpha equivalence?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-inference, unification

I was reading about type unification and it moves through of substitution of variables. To me it looks like a search for an alpha equivalence... I mean, two types are unifiable if they are alpha equivalent, at last if they are in polymorphic form, is this right?

If I have `forall a.a -> a` and `forall b.b -> b` I can apply `[b/a]forall a.a -> a` to achieve `forall a.a -> a`. So they are unifiable!?

Going deeper I could unify `forall a.a -> a` to `int -> int` and then deduce that the first is more general because I can achieve the second by `[a/int]` substitution on the first right?

Comment: Where were you reading this? It might help to know the context of your question. Certainly unification is *not* $\alpha$-equivalence in general, if that's all you're asking.

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/Lectures/lec26-type-inference/type-inference.htm It was just a reasoning, I read about substitution and then this come to me that type unification may have some parallel with alpha equivalence